# Add values from dialog popup to parent page dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, select, dynamic

Okay, I know what I need to do...I just can't figure out how to write it. Basically, I have a parent page with a table of categories (let's say colors, numbers, letters). These categories are the fathers of the table. The sons are red, blue, 56, 72, abc, def and so on. I have a nyroModal dialog pop up with drop downs to add new rows to this table. I successfully have new rows added, with the correct drop down values added to the parent table on click of my save button but not under the correct "father". They just add to the end of the table. One of the drop downs in the pop up holds the options to the father categories (select name="chooseFather"), this is the only value I can't figure out how to pass.

```
<select name="chooseFather">
<option value="Colors" id="father3">Colors</option>
<option value="Numbers" id="father4">Numbers</option>
<option value="Letters" id="father5">Letters</option>
</select>
```

Each of the parent drop down values have an individual id, that match the id of the parent rows. I need something like a dynamic version of `$(“#parentId”).children().add(your new children)` to capture the chosen drop down value, and place the correct son values in the corresponding part of the table. Here is the code of my save button that transfers my values to the parent table/page.

```
("img.save").click(function () {            

            for(var j=0;j<document.getElementsByName("shoreInfo").length;j++) {
                parent.updateParent1(document.getElementsByName("select1").item(j).value + '&nbsp;' +
                                     document.getElementsByName("text1").item(j).value + '&nbsp; - ' +
                                     document.getElementsByName("select2").item(j).value,
                                     document.getElementsByName("chooseFather").item(j).value);

            }
            parent.$.nmTop().close();
        });
```

Comment: not sure what table structure looks like exactly but you probably want to use `insertafter()` or `after()` methods if inserting directly after a row. If inserting into sub table `append()` to proper table. Very hard to help without seeing html and a demo on jsfiddle.net would really help. Could create simple demo without the modal

Comment: How do I go about creating a dialog on jsfiddle?

Comment: can't you skip the dialog for simple demo? Otherwise can use `Additional resources` to dd scripts and css

Comment: Eek. Does this help? It's not working since I stripped the dialog (probably overlooking something simple, the coffee isn't working this morning) but you can see the syntax markup. http://jsfiddle.net/anschwem/xXeGx/

Comment: would be a lot simpler using different table for each group and wrap in a DIV with a heading. Can make ID of each table match the value of the first select

Comment: Can you make an example with what I gave you?

Comment: not quite sure why I see 3 selects, should add 2 cells for each selection?

Comment: Well, don't take it too literally. I'm not really working on a table for colors, numbers and letters. You can simplify it, the empty cell is really for spacing, so it looks "tabbed" under the father.

Comment: spacing whould be handled with css. Take a look at demo in my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you were to modularize the html a bit as follows:

```
<div class="widget_group">    
    <h3>Colors</h3>
    <table id="Colors"></table>
</div>

<div class="widget_group">    
    <h3>Numbers</h3>
    <table id="Numbers"></table>
</div>
```

You can then use the value of the first select to target the table ID wanted.

Also note adding ID to important elements you want to access can simplify code

```
<select  value="3" id="chooseFather">
```

Adding row using jQuery:

```
$("img.save").click(function () {
    if( !validateSelections()){
        alert('select one of each');
        return;
    }

    /* note that ID attribute was added to each "select"*/
   var tableID= $('#chooseFather').val();
    var newRow='<tr><td>'+$('#select1').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#select2').val()+'</td></tr>';

    $('#'+ tableID).append( newRow)

});


function validateSelections(){
    return $('#chooseFather').val() && $('#select1').val() && $('#select2').val();
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xXeGx/1/

Also use of font tags is deprecated, use class added to element and css instead

Comment: Well, it seems to make sense but it's not working on the jsfiddle. Plugging it into my page isn't working either.

Comment: I'm testing the site in Internet Explorer unfortunately, but I tested the jsfiddle in IE, Chrome and Mozilla and it won't even get to the alert.

Comment: OK I didn't notice you had "undefined" in select values. Have to modify the validation function... did you not try adding a row?

Comment: I've tried adding a row, no luck. Did you update your jsfiddle? It's still not working for me.